# Toshiba Laptop Satellite Pro S500 OCZ Vertex Series SSD error

Tags: ssd

I purchased a new [Toshiba s500](http://www.mytoshiba.co.nz/support/notebooks/satellite/pro/s500/psse0a-08000r/download?os=25) laptop and installed a [OCZ Vertex Series SATA II](http://www.ocztechnology.com/products/solid_state_drives/ocz_vertex_series_sata_ii_2_5-ssd) 60 GB SSD , but cannot install Windows 7 64 bit Pro on it. The laptop gives these errors : [link](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0NJuNGnNU9yMWIyNDBjMWItYTg1Ny00NzBkLTgwZGUtZThjYWRlYzA2ZWQz&hl=en&authkey=CJ-zxI8G) and [link](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0NJuNGnNU9yMmMyM2Y3M2EtZDE1NC00NmY2LWE1MzktZGEwNGE4MWRhNWVh&hl=en&authkey=CO2GkrYC) . For installing Windows, I cloned the  HDD(fresh out of the laptop box) onto the new SSD and performed an install for factory settings. I also the upgraded the BIOS to the latest version from the toshiba website(booting from the HDD). How can I install Windows 7 into this from a DVD because Toshiba doesn't give any DVDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in the BIOS settings that AHCI is either turned on or off, because if the Factory Restore image was made with AHCI off, and you are cloning it to your new drive with it on, there will be problems, primarily bluescreens of death. Also, try installing Windows 7 off of a DVD if you can borrow someone's install DVD as this will rule out my previous tip.

Comment: Thanks a bunch...AHCI was turned on in the BIOS when I first went to the BIOS..yes there was a BSOD when Windows 7 tried to install to the SSD..How can I install Windows 7 (my license) into this from a DVD because Toshiba doesn't give any DVDs.

Comment: You can download an ISO from the internet for free, its just the Product Key that matters when it comes to activating Windows, as well as getting the correct drivers from Toshiba's website afterwards.

Comment: I updated the question..thanks..let me try..should i try on a OCZ or Intel?should i try on a 64gb or 120 gb

Comment: How much are you willing to spend? Personally, I'm an Intel fanatic, but thats just me.

Comment: i think I am willing to use something that is going to work with my laptop and is of size 60-120gb